# RDP saved credantials doesn't work

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, group-policy, windows-domain, security-policy

I'm trying to connect to a domain computer there is a message:
"the server's authentication policy does not allow requests using saved credentials"

[image]

I tried to search for the solution on the Internet. I've changed the registry setting:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]

"PromptForCredsOnClient"=dword:00000000

"DisablePasswordSaving"=dword:00000000
```

But the same message still appeared furthermore every time after an "unsuccessful" connection attempt those registry keys reset back to 1.

Remote box settings:
[image]

Comment: Have you made the registry changes on the server or the client? The screenshot seems to be taken on a Windows 7/8 machine, what version is used by the server?

Comment: @Robert I've updated the screenshot. Sorry, It made you confuse. I've made registry changed on the workstation I'm trying to connect from. I'm trying to connect to another workstation both are Windows 10 machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is on the remote box, specified under group policy. You need to run `gpedit.msc` on the remote box, and change `Do not allow passwords to be saved` to False.

The setting is under `Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services`.

However, if the setting is specified as True on AD, then a `gpupdate` will set it back.

Comment: I've changed registry settings on the remote box as you advise me. It still asks to re-enter credentials

Comment: It may need a reboot, or it may have been overwritten by a group policy update.

Comment: @spike_richie It seems you are right. After making registry changes the remote box needs to be rebooted.

Comment: @user2978216 I invite you to mark the answer as solving your question and/or upvoting it.